# How to get data by ID in Angularjs php and mysql

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, angularjs

I have setup a basic angularjs application. I can connect with the database and get data by using $http service. However I cannot figure out a way to display single item by its ID. Please help me in displaying the single data by ID when clicked.

Thank you

MySQL Connection:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM categories";
$qry = $conn->query($sql);
$data = array();
if($qry->num_rows > 0){
    while($row = $qry->fetch_object()){
        $data[] = $row;
    }
} else {
    $data[] = null;
}

$conn->close();
echo json_encode($data);
```

HTML NG-REPEAT

```
<section class="container-fluid is-grey" ng-controller="categoryController" style="border-bottom: 0;">
<div class="row">
    <ul class="list-inline">
        <li ng-repeat="cat in categories" class="col-md-3" style="padding-left:0; padding-right:0;">
            <a href="#">
                <div class="item-thumbnail">
                    <img ng-src="images/categories_images/{{ cat.cat_image }}" class="img-responsive">
                </div>

                <div class="item-details">
                    <h4>{{ cat.cat_name }}</h4>
                </div>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
</section>
```

ANGULAR APP:

```
  var dsApp = angular.module('dsApp', []);
  dsApp.controller('homeController', ['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.title = 'Digital Solutions Technologies';
  }]);

  dsApp.controller('categoryController', ['$scope', '$http',  function($scope, $http){
    $http.get("_admin/db.php")
    .then(function(response) {
        $scope.categories = response.data;
    });

  }]);
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate on *I cannot figure out a way to display single item by its ID*?

Comment: In PHP we pass a variable in URL like <a href="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"> My link </a> and in the other page we user $_GET variable to retrieve data assigned to the URL href variable. I would like to understand how can I achieve the same in AngularJS. I have created details.js page where I want to display singe product details.

Comment: Doesn't you retrieve `Id` property with category record??

Comment: I can retrieve ID and data on the home page but I want to display the details of the product in details page. I have already added <a ng-href="details/{{ cat.cat_id }}">  tag, now I want to display the product details based on the product ID